# ajax action method returns aborted session when calling form.submit()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm pulling my hair out on this one.  I don't get what's going on.

I have an Action method which returns some JSon from a Post method.  There is no authentication on this method.  It's an adaptation of the MVC 4 AjaxLogin system (but using it in MVC3)

The form does a .post(), containing the serialized data.  If it fails validation, it ruturns a collection of errors.  The code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JsonLogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }

    // If we got this far, something failed
    return Json(new { success = false, errors = GetErrorsFromModelState() });
}
```

This is called in the following jquery in a method attached to a submit handler.

```
if (!$form.valid || $form.valid()) {
    $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray())
        .done(function (json) { ... });
}
```

this is the weird part.  If i use a submit button, everything is fine.  The method returns with a status of 200 (and selecting properties on the request in fiddler shows SESSION STATE: Done.), and the .done() executes.

If i use some javascript to call form.submit(), then it does the post, but the http request always fails with a SESSION STATE: Aborted. (still returns a 200 result code according to fiddler) and .done() is never executed.

There is literally no difference between any header or data sent to the action method in either case, yet it always aborts when using .submit() and always succeeds when using the submit button.

I attach the submit handler like this:

```
// Load the dialog with the content=1 QueryString in order to get a PartialView
$.get(url + separator + 'content=1')
    .done(function (content) {
        dialogs[id] = $('<div class="modal-popup">' + content + '</div>')
                // (jquery ui dialog code omitted for clarity)
                .filter('div') // Filter for the div tag only, script tags could surface
                .find('#frm_login') // Attach logic on forms
                    .submit(formSubmitHandler)
                .end();
        });
```

This one is driving me crazy.  Any suggestions on finding the reason why this is aborting?

EDIT:

Browser version doesn't matter, it does the same thing on IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc..

EDIT2:

I tried to just click use JS to click the submit button and it also fails.

It seems to be tied to the fact that i'm executing the submit from a link href like this:

```
<div id="loginBn"><a href="javascript:$('#blah').click();">Login</a></div>
```

The following code succeeds.

```
<button onclick="javascript:$('#blah').click();"></button>
```

It shouldn't be trying to navigate anywhere given the javascript reference, but it seems to be aborting because of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you use the href property of a link to call javascript, then it will issue an abort to any ajax request that executes from it.  I fixed it by using the onclick handler of the link instead.